# How we can login in salesforce communities using Gmail and LinkedIn?

Tags: oauth2, login

I am able to login using Gmail and LinkedIn individually. I am not able to display both the Option available in My Domain Authentication Configuration setting. I can see only one option for Gmail. How we can give both option to user login via Gmail or LinkedIn?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login_with_LinkedIn) which tells how to setup LinkedIn login

Comment: please avoid link only answers, put a summary of the article into the answer - e.g. headline points.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am able to login via LinkedIn and Gmail. I created two Auth. Providers one for Gmail and second for LinkedIn. I want to give both options to login in to salesforce. Problem is I can see only option in Authorization Configuration screen. Is there any way to give both option to login in salesforce?

Comment: Are you referring "Authentication Configuration" as "Authorization Configuration"  screen?

Comment: Yes "Authentication Configuration".

Comment: @Sunil I created two connected apps for Google and Linkedin for testing and I can see both options available in the login configuration page.